# Spring Cloud API Gateway JWT Issue Web Token Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I have a problem about sending any request to a defined service through api gateway with the usage of bearer token coming from login.

After login, I tried to send a request to a defined service but I got this issue in JWTAuthenticationFilter of api gateway shown below.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.setSigningKey(DefaultJwtParser.java:151) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.microservice.apigateway.util.JwtUtils.validateJwtToken(JwtUtils.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microservice.apigateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.filter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(FilteringWebHandler.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4455) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4455) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.23.jar:3.4.23]
    
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.setSigningKey(DefaultJwtParser.java:151) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.microservice.apigateway.util.JwtUtils.validateJwtToken(JwtUtils.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microservice.apigateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.filter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:55)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
```

The exact location is in JWTUtils class with this line shown below.

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the repository : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Here is the screenshots : [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BCMSj9STszd-GaHWJZE4a0IuLpUcXBxj?usp=sharing)

**Edited**

After I added this dependency in pom.xml of api gateway shown below I got this issue.
Here is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.jsonwebtoken.Claims.get(Object)" because "claims" is null
    at com.microservice.apigateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.filter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Gateway does not depend on this class. I have no idea who manages com.microservice.apigateway

Comment: @spencergibb The api gateway has also JWTUtils class.

Comment: `com.microservice.apigateway.util.JwtUtils` is not from spring cloud

Comment: @spencergibb How can I fix the issue? I still couldn't fix it.

Comment: I don't know. I don't maintain that class or even know where it comes from

Comment: @spencergibb I added some screenshots.

Comment: @spencergibb I still couldn't fix the issue even if I added a dependency named jaxb-api in the pom.xml of api gateway.

Comment: Can you paste a jwt token example?

Comment: @Alex I shared the answer. Can you also help me my another issue regarding jwt again if you don't mind? It is my latest post.

Comment: @ALex Can you look through my another question if you don't mind? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586470/spring-boot-microservices-spring-cloud-403-forbidden-among-services-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I revised some codes in **JWTUTils** in **API Gateway**, the issue disappeared.

Here is the solution

```
final String authorization = request.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("Authorization").get(0);
final String token = authorization.replace("Bearer ", "");
jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(token);
```