# Spring Boot Microservices (Spring Cloud) , 403 Forbidden among services (Controller and ControllerTest)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-cloud

I have a communication problem in my spring boot microservices.

I created some services as well as eureka server, api gateway and config server.

I defined auth service connecting to api gateway for the process of authentication and authorization. I used this service as creating a user, logining and refreshing token.

After I created a user and login in auth service through the port number of api gateway, I tried to make a request to the order service like `http://localhost:9090/order/placeorder` or `http://localhost:9090/order/{order_id}` but I got 403 forbidden issue.

I knew there can be spring security problem among api gateway, auth service and order service but I couldn't find where the issue is.

Except for that, I cannot run any test method defined in OrderControllerTest because of this reason.

How can I fix these issues?

I shared some code snippets regarding security config defined in 2 services and api gateway and gateway filter located in api gateway.

Here is **SecurityConfig** in **auth service**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    private final JWTAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(jwtUtils,customUserDetailsService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authenticate/signup","/authenticate/login", "/authenticate/refreshtoken");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter(JwtUtils jwtUtils, CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        return new AuthTokenFilter(jwtUtils, customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Here is **SecurityConfig** in **api gateway**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity){

        serverHttpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .anyExchange()
                        .permitAll());
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }


}
```

Here is the **gatewayconfig** in **api gateway**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GatewayConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter filter;

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes().route("AUTH-SERVICE", r -> r.path("/authenticate/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter)).uri("lb://AUTH-SERVICE"))
                .route("PRODUCT-SERVICE", r -> r.path("/product/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter)).uri("lb://PRODUCT-SERVICE"))
                .route("PAYMENT-SERVICE", r -> r.path("/payment/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter)).uri("lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE"))
                .route("ORDER-SERVICE", r -> r.path("/order/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter)).uri("lb://ORDER-SERVICE")).build();
    }
}
```

Here is **SecurityConfig** in **order service**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/order/**")
                     .access("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER') or hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Here is the **OrderControllerTest** shown below.

```
@SpringBootTest({"server.port=0"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {OrderServiceConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class OrderControllerTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    static WireMockExtension wireMockserver
            = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
            .options(WireMockConfiguration
                    .wireMockConfig()
                    .port(8080))
            .build();

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper
            = new ObjectMapper()
            .findAndRegisterModules()
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() throws IOException {
        getProductDetailsResponse();
        doPayment();
        getPaymentDetails();
        reduceQuantity();
    }

    private void reduceQuantity() {
        wireMockserver.stubFor(put(urlMatching("/product/reduceQuantity/.*"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)));
    }

    private void getPaymentDetails() throws IOException {
        wireMockserver.stubFor(get("/payment/order/1")
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withBody(copyToString(OrderControllerTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mock/GetPayment.json"), defaultCharset()))));
    }

    private void doPayment() {
        wireMockserver.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/payment"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)));
    }

    private void getProductDetailsResponse() throws IOException {

        wireMockserver.stubFor(get("/product/1")
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withBody(copyToString(
                                OrderControllerTest.class
                                        .getClassLoader()
                                        .getResourceAsStream("mock/GetProduct.json"),
                                defaultCharset()))));
    }

    private OrderRequest getMockOrderRequest() {
        return OrderRequest.builder()
                .productId(1)
                .paymentMode(PaymentMode.CASH)
                .quantity(1)
                .totalAmount(100)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Place Order -- Success Scenario")
    @WithMockUser(username = "User", authorities = { "ROLE_USER" })
    void test_When_placeOrder_DoPayment_Success() throws Exception {

        OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
        String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleUser();

        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeorder")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String orderId = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(orderId));
        assertTrue(order.isPresent());

        Order o = order.get();
        assertEquals(Long.parseLong(orderId), o.getId());
        assertEquals("PLACED", o.getOrderStatus());
        assertEquals(orderRequest.getTotalAmount(), o.getAmount());
        assertEquals(orderRequest.getQuantity(), o.getQuantity());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Place Order -- Failure Scenario")
    @WithMockUser(username = "Admin", authorities = { "ROLE_ADMIN" })
    public void test_When_placeOrder_WithWrongAccess_thenThrow_403() throws Exception {


        OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
        String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleAdmin();

        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeorder")
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isForbidden())
                .andReturn();

    }


    @Test
    //@WithMockUser(username = "Admin", authorities = { "ROLE_ADMIN" })
    public void test_WhenGetOrder_Success() throws Exception {

        String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleUser();

        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/order/1")
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String actualResponse = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        Order order = orderRepository.findById(1l).get();
        String expectedResponse = getOrderResponse(order);

        assertEquals(expectedResponse,actualResponse);
    }

    @Test
    //@WithMockUser(username = "Admin", authorities = { "ROLE_ADMIN" })
    public void testWhen_GetOrder_Order_Not_Found() throws Exception {

        String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleAdmin();

        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/order/4")
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNotFound())
                .andReturn();
    }

    private String getOrderResponse(Order order) throws IOException {
        OrderResponse.PaymentDetails paymentDetails
                = objectMapper.readValue(
                copyToString(
                        OrderControllerTest.class.getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("mock/GetPayment.json"
                                ),
                        defaultCharset()
                ), OrderResponse.PaymentDetails.class
        );
        paymentDetails.setPaymentStatus("SUCCESS");

        OrderResponse.ProductDetails productDetails
                = objectMapper.readValue(
                copyToString(
                        OrderControllerTest.class.getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("mock/GetProduct.json"),
                        defaultCharset()
                ), OrderResponse.ProductDetails.class
        );

        OrderResponse orderResponse
                = OrderResponse.builder()
                .paymentDetails(paymentDetails)
                .productDetails(productDetails)
                .orderStatus(order.getOrderStatus())
                .orderDate(order.getOrderDate())
                .amount(order.getAmount())
                .orderId(order.getId())
                .build();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderResponse);
    }

    private String getJWTTokenForRoleUser(){

        var loginRequest = new LoginRequest("User1","user1");

        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(loginRequest.getUsername());

        return jwt;
    }

    private String getJWTTokenForRoleAdmin(){

        var loginRequest = new LoginRequest("Admin","admin");

        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(loginRequest.getUsername());

        return jwt;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class LoginRequest {

        private String username;
        private String password;

    }

}
```

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Here are the screenshots : [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BCMSj9STszd-GaHWJZE4a0IuLpUcXBxj?usp=sharing)

**To run the app,**

1 ) Run Service Registery (Eureka Server)

2 ) Run config server

3 ) Run zipkin and redis through these commands shown below on docker

```
  docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
  docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis
```

4 ) Run api gateway

5 ) Run other services

Comment: Did you check where your requests reach? Do they reach the order-service? Add a breakpoint in the JWT filter of order-service to be sure

Comment: @SergioLema I revised my code two days ago. I tried to fix it but I'm not sure if it is right or not.

Comment: @SergioLema I updated my repository again but I couldn't run any test method in OrderServiceTest and OrderControllerTest. I hope you can help me?